# 'script' command doesn't print anything when started by systemd in TTY

Tags: linux, bash, unix, systemd

**General goal is:** use `rclone` during shutdown for sync with cloud and modify its output a bit. I've created a systemd unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncing with MEGA cloud storage v78
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=yevhenii
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/sbin/auto-sync.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
TimeoutStopSec=0
TTYPath=/dev/console
StandardOutput=tty
StandardError=inherit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It starts `auto-sync.sh` at shutdown and reboot. The script can distinguish one from another and perform sync only during shutdown. Okay, how to modify rclone's output ? The simplest approach is below and it doesn't work since `rclone` detects that its output is not a console and therefore does not print ANSI codes that perform formatting:

```
# doesn't work well, formatting is ugly without ANSI codes
# prints in terminal emulator, prints in TTY during shutdown

rclone sync "$FROM" "$TO" --progress | while read line; 
    do
        echo "[rclone] $line"
    done
```

So, I use `script` utility that performs command's output logging and emulates(!) console for executed command (it preserves `rclone` to print ANSI codes). Exactly what I needed!

```
# works like a charm
# prints in terminal emulator, does NOT print in TTY during shutdown

script --return --quiet --command "rclone sync $FROM $TO --progress" /dev/null | while read line;
    do
        echo "[rclone] $line" #works like a charm
    done
```

**The problem is** that it works in ubuntu terminal emulator and doesn't in TTY that is showed during shutdown. Does anybody know how to fix this ? Thank you!

Comment: Have you already checked that `rclone` doesn't have a `--color=always` like `ls`, `grep` and other tools?

Comment: @thatotherguy sure, rclone doesn't have such an option